# How can I use a "string" to refer to an "linear expression" as an argument inside a Python Gurobi function?

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I have following piece of Python code to define bunch of "obj":

```
obj1=LinExpr(sumOFw_plusPLUSw_minus)
obj2=LinExpr(quicksum(epsilon[s] for s in N))
```

where "sumOFw_plusPLUSw_minus" is an expression and "epsilon" is a Var type.

I want to make it parametric so that I can add more objective expressions later on. In order to apply that I tried to prepare a string inside a loop and call  the above expressions using this string as below, but got a "**GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression**" at line 5.

```
for j in range(1,2):
    for i in range(1,num_obj):
        valid_obj='obj'+str(i)
        if j==1:
            m.setObjective(valid_obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
        else:
            m.setObjective(valid_obj, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
        m.update()    
        m.optimize()
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more code to make your example reproducible? What is exactly `m`, `epsilon`. Thanks.

Comment: N = range(1,row+1)  # number of samples

Comment: m = Model("gurobi_model_name")

Comment: epsilon={}
for s in N:
    epsilon[s] = m.addVar(name='epsilon_%s' % (s))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 'obj' + str[i] is only a Python string, not an object. Gurobi doesn't know how to set the Objective value to a string, it is looking for an objective expression.

To get different objective functions based on a parameter, you can declare Objective costs, and store them in a list. For example:

```
cost =[]
cost[0] = LinExpr(sumOFw_plusPLUSw_minus)
cost[1] = LinExpr(quicksum(epsilon[s] for s in N)) 
...
```

Now you can set the Objective by calling the appropriate the element in the cost list depending on the value of the index `i`. (You can even add different elements so long as they are valid and linear.)

```
valid_obj = cost[i]
```

`m.setObjective(valid_obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)` will work, as long as each element of the list is a valid linear expression of your decision variables in the model `m`.